# How to properly route with angular

Tags: angularjs, ngroute, ng-view, ng-controller

I'm pretty new to angular and i'm trying to make a simple application, that switches few views with ng-view and ng-route.
for some reason, every link that i click always routes me to the same controller (HomeController).

This is my config

```
(function(){
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('app',['ngRoute'])
        .config(myConfig);

    myConfig.$inject = ['$routeProvider'];

    function myConfig($routeProvider){
        //noinspection JSUnresolvedFunction
        $routeProvider
            .when('/',{
                templateUrl : 'templates/home.html',
                controller : 'HomeController',
                controllerAs : 'vm'
            })
            .when('/shop', {
                templateUrl : 'templates/shop.html',
                controller : 'ShopController',
                controllerAs : 'vm'
            })
            .when('/cart', {
                templateUrl : 'templates/cart.html',
                controller : 'CartController',
                controllerAs : 'vm'
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });
    }
})();
```

This is my HTML:

```
<body ng-app="app">
    <div id="site-wrapper">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li class="button"><a href="#/home">Home</a></li>
                <li class="button"><a href="#/shop">Shop</a></li>
                <li class="cart"><a href="#/cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <ng-view></ng-view>
    </div>
    <script src="js/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script src="controllers/CartController.js"></script>
    <script src="controllers/HomeController.js"></script>
    <script src="controllers/ShopController.js"></script>
</body>
```

And here are 2 controllers for example:

```
(function(){
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('CartController', CartController);
        CartController.$inject = ['$scope', '$log'];


    function CartController($scope, $log){
        var vm = this;
        $log.info('Cart CTRL loaded');
    }
})();

(function(){
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('HomeController', HomeController);
    HomeController.$inject = ['$scope', '$log'];

    function HomeController($scope , $log){
        var vm = this;
        $log.info('Home CTRL loaded');
    }
})();
```

Comment: Code looks correct, could you please add plunker/fiddle of the same?

Comment: I used your code and created this plunker. Only difference is I used template instead of template url. Works absolutely fine [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/K3lbYprNAyqzlpo6YQuz?p=preview)

Comment: just noticed that my link is a little strange, this is the index url : http://localhost/Project/#!/ 
and the shop link looks like this : http://localhost/Project/#!/#%2Fshop

Comment: Use ui.router.. That's better..

Answer (score 0):

Off of a quick view, it seems to me that you need to remove the '#' in the href urls. So doing this may work better for you.

```
<nav>
    <ul>
            <li class="button"><a href="home">Home</a></li>
            <li class="button"><a href="shop">Shop</a></li>
            <li class="cart"><a href="cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: I tried it, and it didn't work.
There is something strange with the way my url looks, somehow a #! is added to the end of the url, and also %2F is added.
I think thats what makes the routing break or something, the url looks like this : 
localhost/Project/#!/#%2Fshop

Comment: @Morta1 Thats interesting the %2F is a / that is url encoded.  So it seems as though it is encoding the url for some reason.  I can't outwardly see what the problem is.  Would you be able to put this code in a plnker?